# HTML textarea trigger a 'change' event when modifying its value (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Assume an HTML textarea that you bound the `change` event to it with `textarea.onchange = ...`, or `textarea.addEventListener('change', ...)`.

I want to modify it like `textarea.textContent = '...'` or `textarea.value = '...'` and this to trigger the aforementioned `change` event.

*This is not a duplicate question as the others I've found here imply the use of jQuery. I do not want to use jQuery, I know it saves lives and stuff but I'm fine without it, thanks. :^)*

Comment: So you mean like a watcher that triggers the change event automatically whenever you use `.textContent` or `.value` on that textarea element anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Connum I can define a custom watcher sure but, is there a way for that to happen "automatically"? I mean, like having the DOM trigger the event by itself? Another thing could be to just explicitly trigger the 'change', akin to <element>.click(), but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Well then you could either make your change event callback a named function and call that any time you update the textarea, or you could trigger the change event manually, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: @Connum dispatchEvent is what I was looking for, thanks!